# How to create a modal only if the required fields are filled out before submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a modal appear thanking the user for submitting the form but only if they completely filled out all the required inputs. I like the built in required feature in HTML but currently both pop ups happen when the submit button is pressed. I know an if else statement is required but cannot figure out how to show that the required field is satisfied in JS before popping up the modal.

```
      <!--   THIS IS THE CONTACT FORM SECTION   -->

<section class="contact-form">
  <h1 class="uptop">CONTACT ME</h1>
  <form method="get">
    <input type="text" class = "name required" id="name" placeholder="NAME" required>
    <input type="email" class="email required" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required>
    <textarea id="message" class="message required" rows="5" cols="300" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Tell Me Something Good" >
  </form>
</section>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <p class ="modal-message">THANKS FOR THAT!</p>
  </div>
</div
```

JavaScript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("submit");
var spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var requiredFields = document.getElementsByClassName("required").required;


btnSubmit.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";

}


spanClose.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you attaching the modal onlick to `window.onclick`?

Comment: So if they click anywhere on the window it will close the modal.

Comment: you have to check the value of required fields in btnSubmit.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";

}

function before showing the modal

Comment: Yes I know but I don't know how to check the value of those fields to see if they have been filled out.

Comment: Yes ^^^ you should first apply the logic to submit and then when you get a response you can have to modal pop up

Comment: So basically create the modal pop up in this own function. Then when you submit the form (probably using Ajax?) on success display the form. Of course also add the logic to check if the fields are valid and if they are valid

Comment: @GregStephen check my answer you can do something like that

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help
The `innerHTML` will do the job

```js
function check(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if(name!=''){
    setStatus("Success");
  }else{
    setStatus("Error");
  }
}

function setStatus(message){
  var inputStatus = document.getElementById('msg');
  inputStatus.innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
  <input id='name' name='name' /><span id="msg"></span>
  <button type="submit" onClick="check()">Send</button>
```